# Macbook display flickers with 22" LED Display

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook, hardware-failure, high-resolution

I've purchased an LG 21.5" LED Display with model no. E2250T and I've connected it to my macbook with a mini display to VGA adapter. It work's fine in lower resolutions, but when I choose the best resolution 1920x1020 , display starts flickering randomly and sometimes it goes to power saving mode. I have the same problem with another Monitor-TV (AOC 22") when in high resolution.

The lower resolutions are fine but its not pleasing.
Is it the adapter? I'm connecting displays with a VGA cable since I don't have a mini display to DVI adapter. I can purchase that adapter if it solves my problem.

Comment: You wrote 1980x1020, did you mean 1920x1080? That's the native resolution for the E2250T.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Sorry, My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I purchased the Mini Display to DVI adapter the same day I asked my question and I connected the display with this adapter.

Its fine, and working perfectly. The problem was the VGA adapter.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The [E2250T manual](http://www.lg.com/us/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=E2250T-PN&matchedModelCode=NOT_MATCHED&searchEngineModelCode=E2250T-PN&initialTab=warranty&targetPage=support-product-profile#) says

> ‘Self Image Setting Function’? This function provides the user with optimal display
>   settings.When the user connects the monitor for the first time, this function automatically adjusts
>   the display to optimal settings for individual input signals.

and

> ‘AUTO’ Function? When you encounter problems such as blurry screen, blurred letters, **screen
>   flicker** or tilted screen while using the device or after changing screen resolution, press the
>   AUTO function button to improve resolution.

…

```
Recommended Display Mode for E2250T/E2350T
Mode (Resolution)    Horizontal Freq. (kHz)    Vertical Freq. (Hz)
*12   1920 x 1080    67.500                    60
```

Comment: I've set the display to recommended resolution and setting. But the screen flickers even when using AUTO function.

Comment: I've purchased a mini display to dvi adapter. I'll update this thread once I connect the display with that